# Problems using mailR on Mac to send mail using gmail SMTP

Tags: r, macos, email, gmail

I am having problems getting an R mail script to send mail. I tried sendmailR that does not support authentication but couldn't get that to work and have spent time trying to get the mailR send.mail to work. Here is my code:

```
 send.mail(from = "my.mail@gmail.com",
 to = "my.mail@gmail.com",
 subject = "Subject of the email",
      body = "Body of the email",
      smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.gmail.com", 
      port = 465, user.name = "my.mail@gmail.com", 
      passwd = "my.password", ssl = TRUE),
      authenticate = TRUE,
      send = TRUE)
```

Here are the errors that I get:

```
org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following 
server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465
at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1410)
at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1437)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.NULL
java:597)
at RJavaTools.invokeMethod(RJavaTools.java:386)
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and 
  Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials l135sm1714011oib.8 - gsmtp

at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:892)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:814)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:728)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:386)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:194)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1400)
... 6 more
```

### Error: EmailException (Java): Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465

I am using 2-authentication with Google, but I have an app password set with the SMTP Google server and it has worked fine with all of my mail apps for 3 years. Any advice appreciated.